# Should I use a different framework for my back-end?

Tags: html, frameworks, frontend, backend

Currently I decided to use Bootstrap for my front-end, should I use a different framework for my back-end?

Another question, should my back-end be in a different folder than my front-end? Because my front-end and back-end are inside a folder called Hanuman, they have their own folder inside the Hanuman folder and this is their hierarchical structure

```
Hanuman
```

```
 -> Admin
 -> Public
```

In my back-end and front-end contains a folder called "Style", if I'm to use a single framework for the both of them is that should I just make a folder inside Hanuman folder called "GlobalStyle" and that the both of them should just share it? Or should I give the both of them a copy of the framework?

Solution 1:

Hanuman

```
     -> Admin
     -> Public
     -> GlobalStyle
```

Solution 2:

Hanuman

```
     ->Admin
      ->Framework
     ->Public
      ->Framework
```

EDIT:
**Sorry** that it was messy at first, stupid stack overflow system thinks that I have a code so it wont let me ask the question, I had to use the quote which I thought first was effective but turns out to ruin the hierarchy structure so I edited and fixed it by pretending that it was a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use an entirely different language/environment like Ruby on Rails, PHP, or Python for your back-end development. If you're new to back-end, I would suggest Ruby on Rails, as it is a newbie-friendly language which is simple and easy to understand.

If you decide to use Ruby on Rails, then you can integrate Bootstrap using "gems" and use that as your front-end framework.

If you would like to learn more about Ruby on Rails, [here is a free tutorial book you can read by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book).

Here is a guide to teach you [how to integrate Bootstrap with Rails](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1).

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful suggestion :D Sorry for replying late, I got -4 votes which discouraged me to visit the site again.